# Execute process at install stage, every time

Tags: cmake

I would like to run program to perform do extra installation tasks from CMake. My attempted solution, based on [INSTALL(CODE ...)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/install.html#code) is (this is a real MWE):

```
macro(MY_EXTRA_STUFF ARG)
    execute_process(...)
endmacro()
install(CODE "MY_EXTRA_STUFF(${SOME_ARG})")
```

but CMake complains when I run `ninja install` (or `make install`, depending on generator in use):

```
[0/1] Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:41 (MY_EXTRA_STUFF):
  Unknown CMake command "MY_EXTRA_STUFF".


FAILED: CMakeFiles/install.util 
cd /tmp && /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Is there a way to smuggle my own code into the install stage? The code is too long to fit inside `install(CODE "...")` nicely. A bonus to do it without an external file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code passed to `install(CODE)` is executed as **standalone** CMake code, thus it shouldn't use definitions (functions,macros, variables) from the rest of `CMakeLists.txt`.

That is, `install(CODE)` behaves similar as `install(SCRIPT)` with a standalone script containing given code.

The thing is that *configuration* stage (when you call `cmake` to configure your project) and *installation* stage, which, as you can see, calls `/usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake`, are **separate** `cmake` **invocations**. These invocations parse different files, so they unaware about context of each other.

Comment: This was helpful. What I did based on your answer was `configure_file(foo.cmake ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cmake @ONLY)`, then `install(SCRIPT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cmake)`. The original `foo.cmake` will have `@VARIABLES@` replaced from the main script (while `${VARIABLES}` will be left alone) and contains the installation logic. The substitution had to be done as `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` at install stage in fact points to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, for some strange reason.

Comment: "`${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` at install stage in fact points to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, for some strange reason." - Yes, as noted in the answer, the installation step is performed by CMake with `/usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake`. This is a *script mode* of CMake, and, as stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html), variable `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is set to the current working directory (which is the top-level build directory for the "main" project).